# ResizeNode subscribes and publishes camera info on the same topic

Tags: ros, ros2, image-proc, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like a dumb question, but I can't find the answer.

I see that image_proc::ResizeNode subscribes to /camera_info, and then generates a new CameraInfo message with the scaled intrinsics. But it publishes this scaled camera info on the the same topic. The messages are identical except for fx, fy, cx and cy. How can a downstream node tell them apart? How does this work with image_transport?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389072/resizenode-subscribes-and-publishes-camera-info-on-the-same-topic/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2021-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-21**:
That doesn't sound like what should be happening.

> How can a downstream node tell them apart?

it would not be able to. Or at least not in any scalable way.

Could you link to the code (as in: specific lines)? I'm assuming you're looking at the default implementation, which is hosted in a Github repository.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2021-10-22**:
ROS2 version uses an image_transport::CameraPublisher and an image_transport::CameraSubscriber:

https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/c8a1f4fea5902214d8bc4b7562e4199837b4b776/image_proc/src/resize.cpp#L53

Both of these call image_transport::getCameraInfoTopic:

CameraSubscriber: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/blob/b2d8d5cbaf3edad81f02c572f073368f7ce17615/image_transport/src/camera_subscriber.cpp#L125

CameraPublisher: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/blob/b2d8d5cbaf3edad81f02c572f073368f7ce17615/image_transport/src/camera_publisher.cpp#L92

image_transport::getCameraInfoTopic basically always returns "/camera_info":

https://github.com/ros-perception/image_common/blob/b2d8d5cbaf3edad81f02c572f073368f7ce17615/image_transport/src/camera_common.cpp#L60

This looks like a bug to me. It seems funny that this hasn't been noticed before, though.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2021-10-22**:
ROS1 is different... it uses a private node handle for pub and node handle for sub. It's been a while since I've used ROS1, perhaps it's possible to distinguish between them through remapping?

https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/noetic/image_proc/src/nodelets/resize.cpp

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2021-10-25**:
Looks like a bug has already been reported: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/703

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bug reported here: https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/703

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2023-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0